# Can not acces Gmail.com, SSL error

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, firefox, gmail, ssl

I'm using a wired router connected to a ADSL line to conect my computer to internet, 
When I try to access **gmail.com** using Firefox it gives following error,

```
Secure Connection Failed
An error occurred during a connection to accounts.google.com.
SSL peer reports incorrect Message Authentication Code.
(Error code: ssl_error_bad_mac_alert)
```

Internet Explorer does not load the page nor gives any error.

Tried setting Time in Windows and Router Configuration as sugested in some forums, also tried using a different router and different OS (Windows7 and Windows XP) but no avail, but worked perfectly when using a dongle (different internet connection) insted of the LAN.

Any suggestion that I can try to fix this issue?

Comment: Do have proxy server configured in your browsers?

Comment: @Khaled No, its a Home computer, no proxies. Also this happened suddenly, Didn't change any configuration or hardware.. :(

Comment: There were apparently Gmail service issues on 4/17.  Is it still a problem?

Comment: @uSlackr Yes, Now its working fine.. :)  Actually Problem was there for about 2,3 days. Should be a problem with Gmail service as you said...

Comment: Now the problem is gone, Thanks everyone for Comments and Answers....

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because your browser cannot open https sites, I believe. Try changing browser or updating it; might help.